# Wifi Signal strength in IOS8

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone-privateapi, signal-strength

My App used to measure the Wifi Signal strength . For that I have used a private API in iOS7

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);
```

But now it seems that Apple has removed it to some other Location in iOS8. As i am not able to find these methods .

```
apple80211Open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
apple80211Bind = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
apple80211Close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
apple80211GetInfoCopy = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211GetInfoCopy");
```

So do Any one has any idea where it may have been removed/replaced.

Is there any other way of measuring the Wifi Strength. (value something like : - 47)

Earlier apple80211GetInfoCopy used to return

```
"AUTH_TYPE" =     {
    "AUTH_LOWER" = 1;
    "AUTH_UPPER" = 8;
};
BSSID = "74:XX:XX:60:1b:XX”;        // Value changed for security.
CHANNEL =     {
    CHANNEL = 149;
    "CHANNEL_FLAGS" = 20;
};
NOISE =     {
    "NOISE_CTL_AGR" = "-85";
    "NOISE_UNIT" = 0;
};
"OP_MODE" = 1;
POWER =     (
    1
);
POWERSAVE = 1;
RATE = 135;
RSSI =     {
    "RSSI_CTL_AGR" = "-47";
    "RSSI_UNIT" = "-1";
};
SSID = <6d506f72 74616c20 4343>;
"SSID_STR" = “Wifi XX;              //Value Changed for Security
STATE = 4;
```

Where RSSI_CTL_AGR  is what i need to fetch .

PS:The App is not for APPStore . Its for adhoc distribution.

Comment: I haven't looked around too much, but have you poked around in the private MobileWiFi.framework?  MobileWiFi-Symbols.h reveals _WiFiManagerClientGetPower, which smacks of what you're after.

Comment: Any update on this? Please let me know.. I am trying to do the same..